# Discord.js getting data from a JSON file returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to access data from an `orders.json` file. It should list all `orders`, however, it says "undefined" when I try to do that as shown in the pic below:

[image]

It also does the same thing when there aren't any `orders` in the JSON file:

[image]

`.list` command's code:

```js
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'list',
    description: 'List of all orders',
    aliases: ['allorders'],
    execute(message) {
        

        fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
            let orderString;
            for(let x in orderDB) {
                orderString = orderString + "`" + x + "`: " + orderDB[x].status + "\n";
                // add newline character at the end to display each "order" on a separate line
            }
            const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Here\'s a list of the current orders and their status.')
                .setDescription(orderString)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
            message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        });
    }
}
```

data in the json file are stored like this:

```js
{
    "tip": {
        "orderID": "tip",
        "userID": "734532125021307001",
        "guildID": "745409671430668389",
        "guild": "Cybers Taco Stand Server",
        "channelID": "746423099871985755",
        "order": "a",
        "customer": "Aro#1221",
        "status": "Unclaimed",
        "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty obvious, you defined `orderString` but didn't assign a value to it and then you did:

`` orderString = orderString + "`" + x + "`: " + orderDB[x].status + "\n"; ``

But `orderString` isn't defined, so it would definitely says `undefinedtip`.

Answer (score 0):

A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type `undefined`. When you declare the variable `orderString` and don't assign a value, it will be `undefined`.

Unfortunately, JavaScript allows concatenating different types by simply converting non-strings to strings. In this case `undefined` will be `"undefined"`.

```js
let undef;
let str = 'string';
console.log(undef + str)
```

To solve your issue, you can assign an empty string to `orderString`:

```
let orderString = '';
```

Check the snippet below. I also tried to simplify the string concatenation with the use of template literals.

```js
const orderDB = {
  "tip": {
    "orderID": "tip",
    "userID": "734532125021307001",
    "guildID": "745409671430668389",
    "guild": "Cybers Taco Stand Server",
    "channelID": "746423099871985755",
    "order": "a",
    "customer": "Aro#1221",
    "status": "Unclaimed",
    "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set"
  },
  "ysh": {
    "orderID": "ysh",
    "userID": "734532125021307001",
    "guildID": "745409671430668389",
    "guild": "Cybers Taco Stand Server",
    "channelID": "746423099871985755",
    "order": "a",
    "customer": "Aro#1221",
    "status": "Ready",
    "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set"
  },
}
let orderString = '';

for (let key in orderDB) {
  orderString += `\`${key}\`: ${orderDB[key].status}\n`;
}

console.log(orderString)
```